# row count from second table with more than one table join

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have three table:

```
TABLE1:

jobposts (id,user_id,qualification_id)

TABLE2:

appliedjobs (id,jobposts_id,message)

TABLE3:

qulificationmasters (id, qualificationame)
jobposts_id from TABLE is foreign key of id of jobposts
```

I need all records from jobposts with row count of appliedjobs

I tried by this:

```
$jobposteddetails = DB::table('jobposts')
    ->rightJoin('qulificationmasters','qulificationmasters.id', '=', 'jobposts.qualification_id')   
    ->leftJoin('appliedjobs','appliedjobs.jobposts_id', '=', 'jobposts.id')
   ->select('jobposts.*','qulificationmasters.QualificationName', DB::raw('count(appliedjobs.id) as counts'))
            ->where('jobposts.user_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->groupBy('appliedjobs.id')
            ->get();
```

But gives error like: it wants every column in groupby of jobposts and qulificationmasters and qulificationmasters.id

But gives error like: it wants every column in groupby of jobposts and qulificationmasters and qulificationmasters.id

If I groupby with all columns of jobposts and qulificationmasters then it is working good.
But why all the columns gropuby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go in config folder database.php  find mysql array and make strict to false and check again.

Comment: But why strict false?

Comment: Strict mode controls how MySQL handles invalid or missing values in data-change statements such as INSERT or UPDATE. A value can be invalid for several reasons. For example, it might have the wrong data type for the column, or it might be out of range. A value is missing when a new row to be inserted does not contain a value for a non-NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause in its definition. (For a NULL column, NULL is inserted if the value is missing.) Strict mode also affects DDL statements such as CREATE TABLE.